# Discord Rich Presence Not Connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, nodes

**Objective:** I am trying to make a rich presence for discord.

**Code:**

```
const RPC = require("discord-rpc");
const rpc = new RPC.Client({
    transport: 'ipc',
});

const chalk = require('chalk');
const settings = require('./settings.json');
const details = settings.details;
const state = settings.state;
const LIK = settings.largeImageKey;
const LIT = settings.largeImageText;
const SIK = settings.smallImageKey;
const SIT = settings.smallImageText;
const ID = settings.clientID;

rpc.on("ready", () => {
    rpc.setActivity({
        details: `${details}`,
        state: `${state}`,
        startTimestamp: new Date(),
        largeImageKey: `${LIK}`,
        largeImageText: `${LIT}`,
        smallImageKey: `${SIK}`,
        smallImageText: `${SIT}`
    });
    console.log(chalk.green("Rich Prescence is on: " + rpc.user.username))
});


rpc.login({
    clientId: `${ID}`,
})
```

**Error:**

```
(node:2128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not connect
    at Socket.onerror (C:\Users\Familia\OneDrive\Documents\Other Stuff\Visual Studio code\Discord Bots\Testing\Art Prescence\node_modules\discord-rpc\src\transports\ipc.js:32:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(node:2128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2128) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

*It says it's not connecting, despite doing everything right. I do not know how to fix this. Help will be appreciated.*

**Edit:** Noticing that I didn't include for websites so I did the following:

```
const RPC = require("discord-rpc");
const browser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
const rpc = new RPC.Client({ transport: browser ? "websocket" : "ipc"});
```

*The same error came up*

Comment: Is Discord open?

Comment: No. I use the website version of discord. Which then i changed the transport to `websocket`. Which gave me an error saying 


`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connection closed
    at WebSocketTransport.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Familia\OneDrive\Documents\Other Stuff\Visual Studio code\Discord Bots\Testing\Art Prescence\node_modules\discord-rpc\src\client.js:118:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at WebSocketTransport.emit (events.js:315:20)...`

Comment: Try using the Desktop version

Answer (score 2):

As [@mark-oe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11895249/mark-oe) stated, you have to be running the Desktop Version of Discord for the RPC to connect to the WSS (WebSockets)

Comment: Yes, this is correct. We need to use the Desktop version of Discord for it to work.